# Webkit version in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I am developing a application based on javascript, it's a web app can run on browser. I intend to port it to a desktop app. I am using OS X 10.6.8 for desktop.

I am using chrome (latest version) for testing my web app, but when porting code to desktop, there are quite lot of bugs. I guess that it has a difference between chrome and webview on OS X 10.6.8. Please let me know which google chrome version that has webkit version is equal to safari 5.1.7 's webkit

Comment: Don't compare apples with bananas ...

Comment: Chrome and Safari are different browsers.  They both use WebKit as a rendering engine, but Safari v5.1.7 uses WebKit 534.57.2, and no version of Chrome uses the same.  What problem are you trying to solve with this question?  Are you trying to support browsers of a certain age?  If we know why you're interested in the similarity of these browsers, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean the [WebKit](http://webkit.org) rendering engine, you can easily compare them by using user-agent strings.

Safari 5.1.7 has AppleWebKit/537.13+

Chrome 24 is the latest version that has AppleWebKit/537.13